# Underscore creating arrays based on object key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Let's say I have a js object such as this

```
{
    a: 5,
    b: 1,
    c: 3
}
```

What I would like to do using Underscore is generate an array which would resemble the following;

```
["a","a","a","a","a","b","c","c","c"]
```

I can achieve what I want with the following code

```
var i = {
    a: 5,
    b: 1,
    c: 3
};

unpack = function (i, item) {
    var items = [];
    _.range(0, i).forEach(function (i) {
        items.push(item)
    })
    return items;
}

console.log(_.flatten(_.map(i, unpack)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VCFZx/ but it doesnt seem the tidiest way of doing it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this `[{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {c}, {c}]`?

Comment: So this `[a, a, a, a, a, b, c, c, c]` is actually an array of strings, not objects?

Comment: So you have a working solution, but are really looking for a code review?

Comment: I guess I was wondering if it was something built into underscore. Cheers for your version.

Comment: I don't know of anything, you could go even further with my solution and using underscore methods to replace for example the `for` loop, but you just add more overhead. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var obj = 
{
a :5,
b : 1,
c : 3
};

console.log( 
  _.flatten(_.map(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
      return _.times(obj[key], function() { return key; });  
  }))
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J6bqb/

Note that this solution is purely functional.

Here is a nicely chained version:

```
  _.chain(_.keys(obj))
    .map(function (key) {
      return _.times(obj[key], function() { return key; });  })
    .flatten()
    .value()
```

Comment: Wonderful, I wasn't aware of the .times utility method.

Comment: `Object.keys` and native `map` in the first example? And then `Object.keys` rather than `_.keys` in the second?

Comment: Good catch. Improved it.

Comment: Better, but the first example is still using native `map` rather than `_.map` :)

Comment: Thank god for chaining :)

Answer (score 2):

In ECMA5 you could do it like this

Javascript

```
function createFilledArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key) {
        var repeat = obj[key],
            count;

        for(count = 0; count < repeat; count += 1) {
            acc.push(key);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
}

var a = {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 1,
    'c': 3
};

console.log(createFilledArray(a));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FhJm9/)

Which in terms of `underscore` would look like this

Javascript

```
function createFilledArray(obj) {
    return _.reduce(_.keys(obj), function(acc, key) {
        var repeat = obj[key],
            count;

        for(count = 0; count < repeat; count += 1) {
            acc.push(key);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/g576p/)

Which if you wanted to go further and replace the `for`

Javascript

```
function createFilledArray(obj) {
    return _.reduce(_.keys(obj), function(acc, key) {
        _.times(obj[key], function() {
            acc.push(key);
        });

        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RgNRj/)

And now for a little interest factor, lets have a look at the performances of the above 3 functions as we introduce more of Underscores methods, and we'll also compare them against the accepted solution by @mrhobo

Here is the [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/22246502)

Something else that none of these take into account, and it is unclear from your question, is whether alphabetical order is a must. If it is then a `sort` will need to be thrown into the mix, as none of these guarantee the ordering.

Finally, in ES3 as mentioned in the comments.

Javascript

```
function createFilledArray(obj) {
    var acc = [],
        key,
        repeat,
        count;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            for (count = 0, repeat = obj[key]; count < repeat; count += 1) {
                acc.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    return acc;
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/289xa/)

I have added the ES3 method to the jsPerf also.

And if you want to chain the result with other Underscore methods.

```
_.chain(createFilledArray(a)).forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: pushing onto an accumulator is to the functional programming people like cursing in church :)

Comment: Sure, I could ES3 it and roll my own/integrate `reduce` using `for` and I could use `for..in` instead of `keys` and integrate that too. It would then most likely be faster than the ECMA5 version. But the comparison was more to show what happens when you move away from the native functions (that includes using `push`) and start using methods from libraries, and as this was a very simple problem then sticking with natives would seem sensible to me.

Comment: sure, using libraries and going functional aren't very helpful in terms of performance: +10